# Magento Default Sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, sitemap, magento

Is the default magento sitemap.xml optimized as is for ecommerce products?  I'm thinking about adding image links as well.  Is it worth time investing in this for SEO gains?

```
<url>
   <loc>
      http://demo.com/product.html
   </loc>
       <lastmod>2011-08-03</lastmod>
       <changefreq>always</changefreq>
       <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet above is about all there is to the sitemap protocol, so basically yes.
Adding images to the sitemap is actually [an extension](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=178636), and wouldn't be a bad idea.